# Function pointer from other class C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dictionary

I have a problem to call a function pointer in map in c++.

**this is my function pointer type:**

```
typedef int (AEvent::*setFunction)();
```

**this is my map :**

```
std::map<const std::string, setFunction *>      _actions;
```

**so i find my function like this:**

```
auto mem = this->_actions.find("SHOOT")->second;
```

and now how can i call the function ?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Those aren't function pointers. Those are pointers to *member* functions. You cannot "call" a member function; rather, you need an object on which you invoke it. For example, it makes no sense to ask how  to call `std::string::clear`; you need an actual string object to clear.

Comment: But I can't do this because if i create an AEvent object i can't instantiate it cause of pure virtual function.

Comment: Are you sure the mapped type is correct? Why a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: (But if you fix the mapped type, the answer is [`(this->*_actions.find("SHOOT")->second)();`](https://ideone.com/0omNqP))

Comment: sorry it's not the good code, i have a reference to setFunction and your reply don't work :/

Comment: it say that i'm not in the good class to call the member function.

Comment: Then replace `this` with a pointer to the appropriate object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have your class hierarchy as follows:

```
class AEvent
{
public:
    virtual int Bar() = 0;
};

class Derived : public AEvent
{
public:
    virtual int Bar() override
    {
        // Return something.
        return 100;
    }
};
```

You can invoke a pointer to member function that is **virtual** as follows:

```
AEvent * my_object = GetDerived();

auto func = this->_actions.find("SHOOT")->second;

(my_object->*func)() // Invoke 'func'
```

If you invoke a pointer to member function, keep in  mind that you are responsible for providing `this` pointer correctly, which in this case happens to be `my_object`

Comment: i did this but now there is a violation access like in my previous code

Comment: The access violation error seems to be no longer relevant to your original question. However if I elaborate a little further,  your `mem` should indicate a valid address to a member function, but the `my_object` (or whatever you've named it) must be problematic somewhat, possibly dereferencing `nullptr`.

Comment: ok so my code was good. Now i have a problem with sfml ;) thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ClémentJean I am glad it helped